# no scrolling with MacBooks trackpad on (previously) animated lists

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

#### My Problem:

In my project, there is an animated container (named `.uebersicht`) who brings in some divs with a scrollable list. The animation flips ([thanks david walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php)) between two different lists in my app. Because both of them should be scrollable I have to flip and kick away the flipped container.

I have simplified my markup and CSS and made a fiddle - but the fiddle is working correct :D (maybe a good trace...) So I put it on a hosting service.

- site (scrolling not working): http://fiddle.bplaced.net/52426221/
- fiddel (same code, works as expected): https://jsfiddle.net/58omteyL/5/

Nevertheless, for a better understanding I visualize my problem:
[image: drawing of my markup]

*(if you wonder about the different containers, they are important for the rest of the app)*

My approach works well on touch and mouse interaction but the Mac trackpad (like the one in a MacBook) and maybe (could not test this) the magic pad and magic mouse on Mac are just able to scroll the container every 2nd/3rd/4th time.

It seems that **Safari 12.0 under MacOS 10.13.6** tries to scroll the wrong container (window-element).

#### Reproduce the bug:

1. check out the fiddle with a MacBook/MagicPad/MagicMouse
2. set 
   your system scrolling direction to *not natural*
3. point in the yellow container and scroll down
4. if this works (sometimes) move and click around (inside or outside the container) and try again

It seems that there is an area in the container where scrolling *never* works.

#### Why this is a SO Question:

You could argue that this is a Safari bug and nothing for SO. But when I'm using [the animations from w3css](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_animate.asp) (unfortunately there is no flip) scrolling works as expected.

---

#### Hints from the Comments here

- When the div is scrolled to the top and you scroll up, the focus goes to the parent and you have to lift the fingers before you are able to scroll down
- My trackpad setting is *not natural* (swipe down = scroll down) changing these setting to *natural* (swipe up = scroll down, this is standard) make my example work
- When scrolling is blocked you can't even scroll with js using `scrollTo` etc. No scrolling event is fired

The question stays the same because I can not ensure that every user has the setting to *natural* and not *not natural* like me.

Comment: Works fine for me on a 2014 Macbook Pro using Chrome

Comment: Just tried on Safari as well.  Works fine for me there.  I'm on OSX 10.14, BTW.

Comment: I've tried around a bit, and this is my finding.
When the container is scrolled to the top (start position), and you put your fingers on your trackpad, and first move up the focus goes to the parent because the container is already scrolled to the top. If you don't lift your fingers, the focus stays on the parent. If you lift your fingers and try to scroll down it should work.

Comment: Hmm... I give it a try, @Simsteve7. I will also update my answer with the Safari version. -Do you see the normal scroll animation (with a bump on the end of the list)?

Comment: I have updated my answer. It seems that the trackpad setting (natural or not natural) is responsible for that. But the problem still persist. I want also users with this setting to be able to scroll...

Comment: Works fine with MacBook Pro 2011 (10.13.6). Safari/Chrome

Comment: Are you sure you set your scrolling to *not natural* !? Seems not...

Comment: I do get the bug as well, with my touchpad (Macbook Pro 2018, Safari 12.0, macOS 10.13.6) and my external mouse, though not consistently. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Maybe it is a problem with the browser, since it works in Chrome/Firefox for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a few good comments here I found a solution but it is more likely a workaround (thanks for your input).

I played around with some `eventListeners`, `capturing` and `bubbling`. It seems that the scrolling goes down to the scroll element (`capture`) but is not bubbling up again. Listen to the scroll event and scroll via JS in the right direction until DOM is unblocked was getting to complicated. But if I modify the style (position/size) of the scrolling element `.styleWrap .scrollable` the blocking was gone !

After that it turns out that it prevents Safari from any blocking when I modify this element after the animation was finished.

So my workaround is to make a style change and revert that after the CSS animation has been finished - and voilà :

```
function slide(slideName){
    // scroll to top
    scroll(0,0);
    // show the Slide
    var slideElement = document.getElementById(slideName);
        slideElement.classList.add('show');
}

setTimeout(function(){
    slide('item1');

    // make a change to be able to revert this change
    var scrollDiv = document.querySelector(".scrollable");
    scrollDiv.style.top = "1px";

    // change some style (reset the prev. change)
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector(".scrollable").style.top = "";
    }, 1300 + 10); // CSS animation time + 10ms

}, 100);
```

Maybe this is the reason why the `w3css` animation does not lead into blocking...

You can test it here *(I add more px to the `top`to make it more visible here)*: http://fiddle.bplaced.net/52426221g/

**I'm not 100% satisfied with this solution because:**

- it is a CSS problem solved with JS
- you need to know the animation timings (which can change with design)

**Therefore I would like to change the *accepted* answer if there is a CSS solution**

Answer (score 0):

I have got the bug on: MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016)

Safari : Version 12.0 (14606.1.36.1.9)

I have added `overflow: hidden` to `HTML, BODY` and seems working. 
It might be related to locking the body while scrolling but not sure.

I can test it again if you update the code by adding

```
html,body {
   overflow:hidden
}
```

Comment: A little bit better. But it persists in the magic area after first load. Try loading the edited page under http://fiddle.bplaced.net/52426222/ and try to scroll directly in the magic area. Scrolling is blocked. After a click in the container scrolling works better und consistent. There is also the MacOS bump at the end of the list. - nearly solved...

Comment: Works fine now and didn't get the first load issue that you mentioned above. 
'content' and 'styleWrap' containers both have 'absolute' positioned. You could consider 'content' wrapper positioned as 'fixed' just to see if that might cause some kind of confusing.

Comment: After the first load (without a click) scrolling does not work sometimes (not necessarily in the magic area...). Changing `position: fixed;` has no effect. Sorry... it seems this was not the right idea...

Comment: try to add scrolling: parent elements too.


`.content, #item1, #list {
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
} `

Comment: You may want to copy the source and try your suggests locally.

Comment: Hi @MichaelP, I have tried adding `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to every element I suspected and didn't get the initial freezing issue on my local tests.
Just wanted you to try and see if that works on your environment too. I don't suggest anything that I haven't tried. Hope you solve the problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to reproduce and trace properly the issue, but what it seems to work on my Mac is to add `overflow:hidden;` also on the other two wrappers `id="item1"` and `class="content"`. In that way the only thing that remains to scroll is the div you want to scroll. I think it could be worth to give it a try.

*MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013)  - OS 10.14.1 - 
Safari version Version 12.0.1. - trackpad natural and not not natural*

Hope this help.

Comment: I made a http://fiddle.bplaced.net/52426221c/ with your description (is it right?) but the problem persists ...sometimes

Comment: @MichaelP Yes, that was what I meant. 
The "sometimes" in your comment is the key I guess, the real issue here. 
The next thing I would try is to set the height of the class="styleWrap scrollable" div.
You could start just adding height: 100%; to that div, as even on the [html, body] css rules.
If it's not enough the next step would be to set a real height [not with a % unit] to the scrollable div. How to do this depends on your context and compatibility you have to achieve (for instance, you could use calc() in the css or opt for some js script instead).